# Hibernate from SQL to HQL - endless loop?

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to convert my Sql queries int HQL because they are easier to manage in views and controllers.

So I have 2 Entity, Luce and Illuminazione. Illuminazione has a ManyToOne annotation with Luce, in this way

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_luce")
    public Luce getLuce() {
        return this.luce;
    }

    public void setLuce(Luce luce) {
        this.luce = luce;
    }
```

Now, I have a list of Illuminazione elements and I need to grab the ones with the maximum date, grouped by Luce elements. In other words, I need to take only the last status for every Luce object from the Illuminazione entity.

The SQL query, which works, is

```
String query = "select i.id_evento, i.id_luce, i.last_date_time, l.numero_luce, l.nome_luce, ill.MaxDate, i.isLit "
    + "from illuminazione i inner join  luci l on i.id_luce= l.id_luce "
    + "inner join (SELECT `id_luce` as numeroLuce2, max(date_time) as MaxDate from illuminazione i2 group by `i2`.`id_luce`) ill "
    + "on i.id_luce = ill.`numeroLuce2` and i.`date_time` = ill.MaxDate order by i.`id_luce` asc";
    SQLQuery q = getSession().createSQLQuery(query);
    q.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
```

I've tried with this HQL query, but i end un in an endless loop... so I think there is something weird..

```
String query = "select i from Illuminazione i where i.dateTime = (select max(ii.dateTime) from Illuminazione ii where i.luce = "
                + "ii.luce)";
```

Is there a way to reach what i need?

**EDIT**
Actually it doesn't go into an endless loop but after 6-7 minutes it finished, and the result is correct, but how it's possibile this long time? It's just 2000 values in the table...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SQL is working, just keep it. Hibernate is not a religion and you will not go to hell for bypassing this abstraction layer.

It will be also easier to debug using a SQL client.

The only drawback is if you have to support multiple database types.

To make things easier, you can execute

```
 String query = "select {i.*} "
        + "from illuminazione i inner join  luci l on i.id_luce= l.id_luce "
        + "inner join (SELECT `id_luce` as numeroLuce2, max(date_time) as MaxDate from illuminazione i2 group by `i2`.`id_luce`) ill "
        + "on i.id_luce = ill.`numeroLuce2` and i.`date_time` = ill.MaxDate order by i.`id_luce` asc";

    SQLQuery q = getSession().createSQLQuery(query)
        .addEntity("i", Illuminazione.class);
```

Comment: with `addEntity` i can use Illuminazione.class naming? The problem was really in using the column names in the view, and not the property of the Java objects... By the way, for knowledge sake, how is it possibile that HQL query takes so long time to do the same SQL query?

Comment: addEntity will do an automatic mapping from the i.* fields. The query will return Illuminazione objects. If you don't need this, you can just use addScalar to get only the required properties. Less abstraction is generally more performances. Hiberate does the HQL compilation and do a mapping for each row.